# doctrine 1.2.3 service for model

Tags: service, model, doctrine-1.2

I have been using Codeigniter with Doctrine 1.2.3 and I am wondering is it possible to use own kind of service classes(like in java ee with hibernate). And how to make those right etc?

Like this:

```
class FeedbacktypeService {
public function getFeedbacksByName($value=''){
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from("Feedbacktype f")
        ->where('f.name LIKE :name', array(':name' => $value));

    return $q->execute();
}}
```

Is there better way to do this? 
Thanks for your answers and opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine Table classes provide dynamic finders for all properties on an object.  If an object "Feedbacktype" has a property "name", you can do:

```
return Doctrine::getTable('Feedbacktype')->findByName($value);
```

It doesn't do LIKE matching, just equality.  It will handle any property, and even combinations of AND and OR properties.

The docs are here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:magic-finders